# Transform array of nested object into flat object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using promise.AllSettled to fetch data from 2 / 3 endpoints and result looks like this

Simplified results array

```js
const results = [
  {
    value: {
      payload: {
      email: "faker@fakemail.pl",
      first_name: "",
      last_name: "",
      pk: 183,
      username: "faker",
      }
    },
    error: true,
  },
  {
    value: {
      payload: {
      avatar: "https://cdn.zeplin.io/faker.png",
      email: "faker@fakemail.pl",
      id: 183,
      is_admin: false,
      username: "faker",
      }
    },
    error: false  
  }
]
```

I would like to get flat object that contains something like this, but generated dynamically (the number of the payloads may vary)

```js
const desiredObj = Object.assign({}, results[0].value.payload, results[1].value.payload)
/*
  avatar: "https://cdn.zeplin.io/faker.png",
  email: "faker@fakemail.pl",
  first_name: "",
  id: 183,
  is_admin: false,
  last_name: "",
  pk: 183,
  username: "faker"

*/
```

Comment: something like `Object.assign({}, ...results.map(x => x.value.payload))`?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, it will be great if you could write an answer I'll gladly mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const results = [
  {
    value: {
      payload: {
        email: "faker@fakemail.pl",
        first_name: "",
        last_name: "",
        pk: 183,
        username: "faker"
      }
    }, error: true
  },
  {
    value: {
      payload: {
        avatar: "https://cdn.zeplin.io/faker.png",
        email: "faker@fakemail.pl",
        id: 183,
        is_admin: false,
        username: "faker",
      }
    },
    error: false
  }
];

console.log(
  Object.assign({}, ...results.map(x => x.value.payload))
);
```

— [Lux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1458413/lux)